Gradle: Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2 and Could not find or load main class worker.*worker.GradleWorkerMain
I cannot build gradle the whole error:
enter image description here
I tried gradle --stop and delate cache(.gradle) and build again
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
$ ./gradlew build
Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: Trwa zamykanie potoku
....

Task :test FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
